# how to store value greater than 200 in tinyint

Tags: mysql, sql

when i tried to store 200 in my `tinyInt` datatype column then it automatically converted that to 127.Is it not possible to store them in my db?

Answer (score 6):

`TINYINT`uses a single byte to hold the value, which gives you -128 to 127 of signed fields, and 0 to 255 on unsigned fields. So yes, if you make the field unsigned then you can store up to 255.